# kubelet breaks CRI standards by running containers in 'k8s.io' containerd namespace?

Tags: kubernetes, containerd

Kubernetes pods run in the 'k8s.io' namespace of containerd. This 'runtime namespace' concept is containerd specific and not a part of CRI.

If kubelet truly follows the CRI standard, then it must not be able to run containers in such containerd namespaces.

crictl does not support this 'runtime namespace' thing and therefore can only communicate to containerd in the default namespace.

This qualifies for a bug report?

Answer (score 1):

The Kubernetes Container Runtime Interface (CRI) defines the main gRPC protocol for the communication between the node components kubelet and container runtime.Your container runtime must support at least v1alpha2 of the container runtime interface.

[crictl](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cri-tools/blob/master/docs/crictl.md) provides a CLI for CRI-compatible container runtimes. This allows the CRI runtime developers to debug their runtime without needing to set up Kubernetes components. This is an expected behaviour in kubernetes v1.29, the kubelet prefers to use CRI v1. If a container runtime does not support v1 of the CRI, then the kubelet tries to negotiate any older supported version. If the kubelet cannot negotiate a supported CRI version, the kubelet gives up and doesn't register as a node.

crictl is currently in Beta and still under quick iterations. It is hosted at the cri-tools repository. Github Community encourages the CRI developers to report bugs or help extend the coverage by adding more functionalities.

Comment: This is not a cri-tools issues. This is a problem with the CRI standard itself or the kubelet implementation of it.

Comment: @user2061812, This is expected behaviour, if the kubernetes is not upgraded, the kubelet will select the older version of CRI which allows all the namespaces for running containers. You can report the behaviour [here](https://discuss.kubernetes.io/) for the CRI.

Comment: Neither old nor new version of CRI support container runtime namespaces.